# How to detect the language of MS Excel

Tags: c++, excel, version

I'm trying to figure out a way of detecting the language of an installed version of Excel (ideally from C++). I need this to resolve an issue with computers on which the language of Excel differs from the Windows language (see [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320369) problem).

Comment: What do you mean by "language?"

Comment: The language of this particular installation - French version, English version, Japanese version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using automation, the applications [`LanguageSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa219863%28v=office.11%29.aspx) object gives you that:

```
Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
```

Comment: Thanks, Georg. Here's a full example of how to resolve the issue I was talking about (in C#) http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/02/13/old-format-invalid-type-library/